# MySQL: How to perform aggregate functions on rows where a column is duplicate, for all values of said column

Tags: mysql

I have a table where one of the columns may have duplicate entries, and I want to condense each set of duplicates into a single row, with an aggregate function applied to the other columns. I cannot think of a sensible explanation of this, so here is an example data table and result table

```
+------------------------+--------------------+
| column_with_duplicates | column_to_aggregate|
+------------------------+--------------------+
| 1                      | 1                  |
| 1                      | 2                  |
| 2                      | 3                  |
| 3                      | 4                  |
| 3                      | 5                  |
| 3                      | 6                  |
+---------------------------------------------+
output

+------------------------+--------------------+
| column_with_duplicates | column_to_aggregate|
+------------------------+--------------------+
| 1                      | 1.5                |
| 2                      | 2                  |
| 3                      | 5                  |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

All of the rows where `column_with_duplicates` is `1` had `column_to_aggregate` averaged together into a result row. The same happened for all values of `column_with_duplicates`

Since I had so much difficulty describing this, I couldn't effectively research the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your query needs to be something like:

```
SELECT 
  column_with_duplicates
  , AVG(column_to_aggregate) AS column_to_aggregate -- AVG does the math, AS gives the name
FROM <table name> 
GROUP BY 
  column_with_duplicates;
```

---

[More information on creating aliases](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) (the `AS` keyword).

[More information on `GROUP BY`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx)

[More information on the `AVG` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) with a handy example that would have served you well.

---

Since you had a question about the `GROUP BY` clause in the comments below...

As I understand it MySQL has [some quirks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html) with it's `GROUP BY` rules. Those quirks not withstanding, I think of a simple `GROUP BY` clause, like the one in the query above, as sorting the result set into buckets. So in our query above there would be one bucket for each unique value in the `column_with_duplicates` column. So each value in the `column_to_aggregate` would get dropped into the proper bucket. Once all the rows/values are sorted into their buckets then an average is taken of all the values **in each bucket individually**.

Of course this is just a conceptual model, but it should give you a basic understanding of the role of a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: That worked, but I'm not sure why avg didn't try to average the whole column. Does `GROUP BY` change the behavior of aggregate functions?

Comment: @klikkkolee What do you mean by "whole column?" If you want an average of all values in the table irrespective of the values in `column_with_duplicates` then you would drop that column from your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses.

Comment: The examples of aggregate functions I found apparently mislead me. The impression they gave me was that aggregate functions took all rows and returned a single number.

Comment: @klikkkolee I just updated my answer with a bucket analogy for group by. Let me know if this helps clear up your confusion. The main take away is that `GROUP BY` collates the data and **gives you one row per grouping**. Since we are grouping by the `column_with_duplicates` all the duplicates are compressed  into one row and the `column_to_aggregate` is aggregated via the `AVG` function.

Comment: apparently I had the meanings of aggregate function **and** `GROUP BY` wrong. Thank you. I was expecting to get a much more complicated result involving sub-queries and joins :)

Comment: @klikkkolee well I can complicate the hell out of it if you'd prefer ;) in all seriousness I'm glad I helped and that the problem is easier than you feared